# Google Sheets regex not matching like other regex apps

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have this google sheets regex:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2, "(?:^|(?:.\s))(\bJohn\b)")
```

Where A2 = "Mike and John"

The result returns TRUE when I expect it to return FALSE.

The purpose of the Regex is to match "John" if and only if it is the complete first word of the cell.

This same regex works as I expect in other regex parsers, I've posted a screenshot of this here:

[Screenshot of Regex not working in google, but works elsewhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MrLB.png)

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern also is not working from the [Regex101 demo site](https://regex101.com/r/v83BDb/1).  I would just use this:

```
^John\b.*$
```

This should match any cell which begins with the entire word `John`, followed by anything else.

Comment: That's much simpler thank you, weirdly the pattern seemed to be working on that site earlier like in my screenshot, but regardless I prefer yours, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following formula

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2, "^John\b")
```